# System Center Configuration Manager Installation Access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, system-center, dcom, com

How to resolve the error during installation of System Center Configuration Manager 2012 with a external MSSQL 2012 Database?

Error Log

```
2/12/2016 7:33:26 AM: ConfigMgrSetupWizard Information: 1 : Reading wmi to get Clustered SQL information on server [SRV-DB-06.******.local].
2/12/2016 7:33:26 AM: ConfigMgrSetupWizard Error: 1 : Exception message: [Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))], Exception details: [System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

The Computer Account as by Microsofts documentation is member of `BUILTIN\Administrators` and `BUILTIN\Distributed COM Users`. The necessary firewall ports are open. And remote management exceptions are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account, that executed the System Center Configuration Manager installer must be added as `BUILTIN\Distributed COM Users`.

If the account is e.g. the `<DOMAIN>\Administrator`, it is not sufficient. You than have to add the `<DOMAIN>\Administrator>` to the `BUILTIN\Distributed COM Users` on the database server and restart the `Windows Management Instrumentation`service.